# why does this jquery snippet does not works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I wonder why this snippet works on chrome (Version 31.0.1650.57 m) and not in firefox (25.0)

```
    <span class="chat-user" id="directeur">
        <a class="user" user="directeur" room="" href="#">
            directeur
        </a>
    </span>
    <script>
    $("a[class=user]").click(function(event) {
        alert();
    }); 
    </script>
```

I click on the "directeur" link, on chrome, I get an alert window, nothing happens in firefox.

**Edit, I found out what was realy the problem**

I was changing the DOM in another function:

```
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $.get("url",
            function(data) {
                data.forEach(function(entry) {
                if (0 != $( ".chat-connected" ).find($("#"+entry.user)).size()) {
                    $("#"+entry.user).find("a").css("color", "red");
                    $("#"+entry.user).find("a").attr("room", entry.room);
                }
            });
        });
    }, 30000);
```

That change was modyfing the DOM and the click jquery function was not applied anymore to the <a> attribute.

Comment: Is the ending actually just `/script>` or is that a typo?

Comment: Have you tried adding text to your alert();?

Comment: Well, when I add a breakpoint on the alert line, the debugger does not break

Comment: I fill ashamed, it's working indeed, my error is somewhere else... cannot find it though and the page is very long, so I'll try to figure out what's going on...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's causing differences between browsers. Perhaps the missing `<` on the `</script>` tag? Anyway, you should really be using

```
$("a.user").click(function(event) {
    alert();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
<span class="chat-user" id="directeur">
    <a class="user" user="directeur" room="" href="#">
        directeur
    </a>
</span>
<script>
$("a.user").click(function(event) {
    alert("It works !");
}); 
</script>
```

Using the CSS selector when it exists is much more straightforward...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change $("a.user").click(...) with **$("a.user").on("click", ...)**